# Colorbox IE7 height issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox, internet-explorer-7

I'm having an issue that only occurs in IE7. Through a JavaScript function, I launch a colorbox. I define the height and width in the parameters.

IE7 seems to render the colorbox 40px shorter in height compared to other browsers. This results to a scrollbar being visible to accommodate the content which is now larger than the colorbox itself.

```
function LoadColorbox(url) {
    jQuery.colorbox({ href: url, iframe: true, opacity: 0.7, height: 560, width: 878, top: 53 });
}
```

Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've solved it.

Root cause: I think there is a difference between the way that colorbox tries to render itself for different browsers such as IE6,IE7,IE8,IE9. I noticed this by inspecting he DOM via IE dev toolbar.

Details: My scenario, I was trying to hide certain elements of the colorbox such as the next and previous buttons but hadn't done so in a sufficient manner for IE7. Whereas on other browsers, the height of the colorbox was excluded from the height of the transparent controls at the bottom, IE7 seem to take into consideration the heights of controls when calculating he height of my content.

My code to fix: 
Colorbox.css

```
    /* Unused elements */
    #cboxTitle,#cboxCurrent,#cboxNext,#cboxNext,#cboxPrevious,#cboxSlideshow,  #cboxTopLeft,#cboxTopCenter,#cboxTopRight,#cboxBottomLeft,#cboxBottomCenter,#cboxBottomRight
    {display:none;height:0px;width:0px;}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have, I belive in my circumstances it was down to a padding/margin issue. Try setting them in there also as 0 and see what that does.

Comment: Hi Graeme, there isn't a margin / padding parameter in colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), I've tried setting all paddings and margins as 0 in the Colorbox.css but with no luck. Any chance you could remember exactly which margin / padding you changed? thanks for your help